# How to make quizzes with text inputs instead of option friendly inputs (radio,list,etc) that still tell you which ones are right and wrong in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I need this for my school project! I also have no clue on how to code this one, so I have nothing to put here. Thank you..

Comment: how does a radio input tell you what's right or wrong in html? How are you wanting to evaluate the question  I would think you would need some logic. This question needs more details. What is it your building exactly.

Comment: i meant if its a radio type input it'd be easier to assign which ones right and wrong since you'd just have to pick "a" "b" or "c" by choosing the intended value in each radio-based question. i'm building an einstein's riddle question with an image of 9 doors with text inputs overlayed on each doors. i'm quite puzzled on how to assign the right and wrong answers with it, hence why i said it's a "quiz".

Comment: i'm sorry if my comment is not gramatically correct/lack details. i'm new and ...fairly young

Comment: That's fine. It still is a little hard to understand your end goal. Do you want someone to fill out these inputs and then hit a submit button and then at that point evaluate if the answers placed in the input boxes are correct. If so you would need some javascript logic. That would compare the input's text to a answer. Is this the case?

Comment: oh!! yes that's the case sir!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this you can play around with it on codepen here https://codepen.io/wispyco/pen/PoPgKzV Try typing in youranswer all one word and hitting submit, and try typing anything else and hitting submit

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>quiz</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input id="answer" type="text">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

js

```
var wordInput = document.getElementById("answer");
var form_el = document.querySelector("form");

form_el.addEventListener("submit", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log(wordInput.value)
    if(wordInput.value==="youranswer"){
       alert("correct")
    }
     else{
       alert("incorrect")
     }
});
```

Comment: i've tried it, now my quiz is almost done. your help will not be forgotten. thank you very very much!! :)

Comment: no problem dont forget to select the answer if it solved it for you. Glad to help